# jQuery で、スクロール追従型にメニューをカスタマイズしたい

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

下記サイトの右メニュー下にある、「スポンサードリンク」のように、スクロールしてもページ内の固定位置に残るメニューを実装したいです。

http://www.akb48matomemory.com/archives/1017688632.html

ただ、以下のようにもしたいのですがこういった実装は可能なのでしょうか。

- 下にスクロールした場合はトップ固定
- 下から上にスクロールした場合はウインドウの下部に固定

お知恵を拝借させてください。  
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 既に退会されたようですね。。。

Answer (score 1):

onscrollイベントのコールバックで現在の「scrollTop」とその前の「scrollTop」を較べていて方向が分かった上で、CSSのposition: fixedとtop: 0かbottom: 0でできます。

下記のように「scrollTop」をどのブラウザーでも計算できます。

```
window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop
```